# Is SSF&F going to get an SO style profile page?

Tags: feature-request

As any users from some of the other Stack Exchange sites (such as Stack Overflow), there is an update user profile floating around that has a sleeker, more fancy layout with relevant information displayed quite prominently. I noticed that English Language and Usage got the update, but I was just curious if it was making its rounds and would come to this site soon or if it were going to be a while.

Comment: After looking at it, it seems as though we are asking the same question. If @Richard wanted to put the answer he posted here (as it is better than the ones given on that answer) I would be happy to close this one down.

Comment: if consensus is that this one is better, we can close the other one as a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Community Managers, the new user profile pages are being rolled out incrementally across a range of different sites.

[List of communities with base css updates completed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253359/list-of-communities-with-base-css-updates-completed)

Allegedy, SFF:SE (and other sites) has proven more challenging because our site has custom CSS and other bespoke design features that would clash.

Patience is advised. They'll arrive soon but we're evidently not a priority.

Comment: Ah, the custom CSS explains why Beta sites got the rollout before SF&F

Comment: @CreationEdge - Indeed. And higher traffic sites seem to be being actioned first.